# Hide "you save" when you have out of stock and hidden price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hide

I use this code to show how much has been saved. It works perfectly. The only problem is that when the products are not in stock, and the prices are hidden, the message in the code, < b> You Save: <, is not hidden. Can anyone help me with modifying / adding this function, meaning that the message "You save" will not be displayed in this case? Thanks..

```
function ts_you_save() 
{

    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) || $product->is_type( 'external' ) || $product->is_type( 'grouped' ) ) {

        $regular_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_regular_price', true );
        $sale_price    = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_sale_price', true );

        if ( ! empty( $sale_price ) ) {

            $amount_saved    = $regular_price - $sale_price;
            $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();

            $percentage = round( ( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price ) * 100 );
            ?>
            <p style="font-size:24px;color:red;"><b>You Save: <?php echo number_format( $percentage, 0, '', '' ) . '%'; ?></b></p>
            if($product->get_stock_quantity()>0) {
echo '<p>Saved</p>’;
}
            <?php

        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'ts_you_save', 11 );
```

Comment: use `$product->is_on_sale()` instead of if it has a sale price.  Since the sale price may not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

function ts_you_save()
{

```
global $product;

if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) || $product->is_type( 'external' ) || $product->is_type( 'grouped' ) ) {

    $regular_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_regular_price', true );
    $sale_price    = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_sale_price', true );

    if ( ! empty( $sale_price ) ) {

        $amount_saved    = $regular_price - $sale_price;
        $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();

        $percentage = round( ( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price ) * 100 );
        
        
        if($product->get_stock_quantity()>0) {
            echo "<p style='font-size:24px;color:red;'><b>You Save: ".number_format( $percentage, 0, '', '' )."%</b></p>";
        }
        

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention, but I couldn't get it to work. Maybe I didn't put it where it should be. Need to be located somewhere?

Comment: Please share code

Comment: I republished the code

Comment: I edited code now you can try it.

Comment: Does not appear edited. The last edit appears to be done, 21 hours ago.

Comment: You cant see it yet:) :Thanks for submitting an edit. It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members.